# Use modal in place of 'show' views

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, modal-dialog

I am trying to use modals in place of the traditional 'show' views in Ruby. When a user clicks on a item in the index view, a modal popup shows instead of redirecting the user to a new 'show' page.

How can I accomplish this?

Let's assume that the controller looks something like this:

```
@list = Items.all
```

I want the modal to show the characteristics of each item on the @list object. For instance, one modal would show @list[0] and another would be @list[1]. How can I pass the index values to the modal?

Comment: So is the user choosing an item from a list then you want to populate a modal with that item's contents?

Comment: Yup, exactly. The user will chose an item from the list and I want to populate the modal with the chosen item's values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach I might take would be, assuming that on your index there is a dropdown and a submit button ...

jQuery

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "items/get_item",
    type: "GET",
    data: { item: $('#select').val() },
    success: function (data) {
      //Populate modal in here with item details
      $('#myModal modal-body').html(data)
    }
  });
});
```

Item Controller

```
def get_item
  return :json => Item.where({:name => params[:item]}).to_json
end
```

View

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body"></div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to render a javascript template from the show action

```
def show
  @list = Items.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render 'your_js_template' }
  end
end
```

Then in your template you can use the `@list` instance variable to create the jQuery for the modal